# Linking to prebuilt libraries with NDK using gradle

Tags: android, android-ndk, gradle

I have an Android project which includes NDK code. From this code, I need to call functions from other libraries built with NDK, which I have in the jniLibs folder:

```
jniLibs/armeabi/libtess.so
jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libtess.so
...
```

if I try to load these libraries from java, as System.loadLibrary("tess"), it works fine.
However, when I try to link my NDK library to it by adding this to build.gradle:

```
ndk {
    moduleName "myJNILib"
    stl "stlport_shared"
    ldLibs "log", "tess"
}
```

it cannot find it.

And of course, if I don't link against it, it cannot compile myJNILib, since it can't find the symbols.
Is there anyway to make this work using gradle? Or I really need to build my library outside of gradle if I want to link with other prebuilt libraries?

Answer (score 0):

What I think you'll want to do is mostly rely on the natural NDK building... stuff... I'm not sure what a good word for that is.

Anyway, you'll want to follow [this](https://gist.github.com/rkbarrett/1ab0c962d3853aee19a7) tutorial. It worked for my own stuff pretty neatly. You'll also, more than likely, want to read [this introduction to Android.mk files](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jDmWgVgorTY_njX68juH5vt0KY_FXWgxkxmi2v_W_a4/edit). It's very helpful for debugging and making sure you're linking correctly.

You may run into two problems in doing this:

1. Undefined symbol errors, which can be an absolute pain. More than likely you will want to eliminate that dependency. I spent hours on this problem and finally concluded that the file must just not *be* there. Somehow.
2. You may also run into it not being able to find an extension of the file you're working on (Ergo, it may say that foo1.so can't find the library foo2.so.# despite you having linked foo2.so. You may have to compile a .a library if that happens, but that may not be the best solution.).

Well, I hope that helps!